# NAudio: Low pass filter

Tags: filter, naudio

Using NAudio I am capturing microphone samples in order to play them back on a remote machine. In some cases I'd like to apply a low-pass filter. How can this done with NAudio?

Ideally I would like to apply the filter based on end user input on the playback machine (maybe via a "enable/disable low-pass filter" button).

It appears as though I need to use...

```
var myFilter = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter (x, y, z);
myFilter.Transform (inBuffer, outBuffer);
```

However, it isn't clear how/where I insert this transformation prior to playback.

I see a few filters in the NAudio library that appear to be what I'd need, unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any samples that make use of them.  Even a simple example in NAudioDemo (Network Chat w/ Filters?) would be great!

Comment: Looking a bit closer at the NAudio library's BiQuadFilter class, it appears as though I would invoke BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter (x, y, z).Transform (inBuffer, outBuffer).  But I have no idea where I would insert this transformation.  Thoughts?